# How to update datatable value after checked or unchecked the checkbox

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have below code, When I checked the checkbox, the value does not reflect in dtWebVo.cpdCourseInfo[??].chkSelect. As I want to get the value and update in the db. How can I do??

```
  <p:dataTable var="cpdCourseInfoDetail" tableStyle="width:auto" 
                                value="#{dtWebVo.cpdCourseInfo}"
                                rowKey="#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.selfInputCourseID}"
                                 selection="#{dtWebVo.selectedCPDCourseInfo}" rowIndexVar="index"
                                 id="gridCourseInfo"  styleClass="ui-edb-td-wrap-table ui-edb-header-style table-no-select-all" >
                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.chkSelect}"
                                disabled="#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.getDisableCheckBox()}" >
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: I am trying to use below code. But disable checkbox does not work.

Comment: <p:dataTable var="cpdCourseInfoDetail" tableStyle="width:auto" 
       value="#{dtWebVo.cpdCourseInfo}"
       rowKey="#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.selfInputCourseID}"
         rowIndexVar="index" selection="#{dtWebVo.selectedCPDCourseInfo}"
        id="gridCourseInfo"  styleClass="ui-edb-td-wrap-table ui-edb-header-style table-no-select-all" >
       
       <p:column id="x_checkbox" selectionMode="multiple" onload="disableCheckBox(this.id,#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.cpdStatusAction})">
       </p:column>

Comment: Please remove all your comments and answer and edit the original question. Way to fragmented this way

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:dataTable var="cpdCourseInfoDetail" tableStyle="width:auto" 
    value="#{dtWebVo.cpdCourseInfo}"
    rowKey="#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.selfInputCourseID}"
    rowIndexVar="index" selection="#{dtWebVo.selectedCPDCourseInfo}"
    id="gridCourseInfo"  styleClass="ui-edb-td-wrap-table ui-edb-header-style table-no-select-all" >
   <p:column id="x_checkbox" selectionMode="multiple" onload="disableCheckBox(this.id,#{cpdCourseInfoDetail.cpdStatusAction})"></p:column>
```

Comment: I am trying to use above code but disable checkbox failed.

Comment: function disableCheckBox(id, checkStatus){
    if(checkStatus=='Submitted')
     document.getElementById(id).disabled='true';
    else
     document.getElementById(id).disabled='false';
   }

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by putting below in datatable tag.

```
<p:dataTable disabledSelection="#{car.color =='Black'}" ... >
```

Comment: Sorry, but this question and answer is totally useless to anybody. It not possible to understand anything. Please remove all.